# How to reorder the x axis by one fill category in a percentage stacked bar chart in gglot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset as below:

```
id=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
total_num=c(40,200,70,40,200,70,40,200,70)
category=c(rep("level1",3),rep("level2",3),rep("level3",3))
value=c(30,160,50,6,30,15,4,10,5)

df=data.frame(id,total_num,category,value)
df$percent=round(df$value/df$total_num,3)
```

I generated the stacked bar chart as below:

```
mycolors<-c("#E78AC3","#E5C494","#66C2A5")

library(forcats)
df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(id,-percent),
             y=percent, 
             fill=factor(category,levels=c("level3","level2","level1"))))+
  geom_bar(position="fill",stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(
    data=df,
    aes(y=percent,
        label = ifelse(category == "level3", paste0(percent*100,"%"), "")),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=2.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors,
                    labels=c('Serious', 'Moderate','Normal')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1,size=10)) +
  labs(x="ID",y="",fill="Level") +  
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks=10,labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1))
```

The figure looked like this:
[image]

I'd like to rearrange the ID by the percentage value when `category=="level3"` (or `"serious"` in the legend label) in a descending order, in this case, it should be 1, 3, 2. So how to modify the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use an `ifelse` in `reorder` to set the values for the other categories to `NA` and using `na.rm=TRUE` order by only the values of your desired `fill` category:

```
library(ggplot2)

df |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = reorder(id,
      # Use only the values for the category you want to order by
      ifelse(category == "level3", -percent, NA),
      na.rm = TRUE
    ),
    y = percent,
    fill = factor(category, c("level3", "level2", "level1"))
  )) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(
    data = df,
    aes(
      y = percent,
      label = ifelse(category == "level3",
        paste0(percent * 100, "%"), ""
      )
    ),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 2.5
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = mycolors,
    labels = c("Serious", "Moderate", "Normal")
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 10
  )) +
  labs(x = "ID", y = "", fill = "Level") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    n.breaks = 10,
    labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution

Comment: Thx @YacineHajji. Your approach is valid as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically define desired levels of you variable `id` as follows.

Here I first change `id` levels based on decreasing order of percent in category "level3".

```
df$id <- factor(df$id, levels=subset(df, category=="level3")[order(subset(df, category=="level3")$percent, decreasing=TRUE), ]$id)
```

Then I modified `ggplot(aes(x=reorder(id,-percent),` with `ggplot(aes(x=id,` because id levels are already defined in your dataframe.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=id,
             y=percent, 
             fill=factor(category,levels=c("level3","level2","level1")))) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill",stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(
    data=df,
    aes(y=percent,
        label = ifelse(category == "level3", paste0(percent*100,"%"), "")),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=2.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors,
                    labels=c('Serious', 'Moderate','Normal')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1,size=10)) +
  labs(x="ID",y="",fill="Level") +  
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks=10,labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1))
```

[image]